# Question for the jquery guru - calculating the total of each in a dynamic line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

rows are added to the table dynamically. The total in the row is displayed in the last input. But only the first row is calculated. What's wrong with the code?

```js
$('table#task').on('mouseup keyup', ['input', 'select'], () => calculateTotals());

function calculateTotals() {
  const subtotals = $('.task').map((idx, val) => calculateSubtotal(val)).get();
  const total = subtotals.reduce((a, v) => a + Number(v), 0);
  $('#totaltask ').attr("value", formatAsCurrency(total));
}

function calculateSubtotal(row) {
  const $row = $(row);
  const inputs = $row.find('input');
  const times = parseFloat($row.find('select option:selected').val(), 10) || 0;
  const subtotal = times * inputs[0].value;
  // console.log(subtotal);
  $row.find('input:last').attr("value", formatAsCurrency(subtotal));
  return subtotal;
}

function formatAsCurrency(amount) {
  return `${Number(amount).toFixed(2)}`;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="task">
  <tr class="task">
    <td>
      <select class="times">
        <option value="0.25">15 min</option>
        <option value="0.5">30 min</option>
        <option value="0.75">45 min</option>
        <option value="1">1 hour</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="rate"></td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input id="totaltask "></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A shot into the dark: You can only once assign a value to variables with keyword "const". Does the same issue appear if you use `var` or `let` instance of `const`?

Comment: Also  HTML having class `task` is missing in your code, so can't tell what's going on

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes - from the second line the amount is not calculated when replacing with var or let

Comment: `<tr>` have `class` task

Comment: How do add a new table row and when?

Comment: is added before the function calculateTotals  at the very beginning of the script. start of code `  $('#addBtn').on('click', function () {
            $('#task').append(`<tr  class="item">`

Comment: THANK YOU ALL!!! Found an error when transferring part of the code to the forum adding `class class items`

Comment: I think you've reversed the parameters when mapping the result of the jquery selector to calculate subtotals. Since you do not need the index of the element to calculate the sub total, I think you want `const subtotals = $('.task').map((val) => calculateSubtotal(val)).get();`